# Neo4j OGM RelationshipEntity when StartNode and EndNode are objects of same type

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am following the Neo4j OGM guide at - http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/

For Relationship entities, we need to have a start node and an end node. I've modified the example a little bit (to make it simpler like this) -

```
@NodeEntity
public class Student extends Entity {
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type= "ENROLLED")
    private Enrollment enrollment = new Enrollment();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
        return enrollment;
    }

    public void setEnrollment(Enrollment enrollment) {
        this.enrollment = enrollment;
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class Course extends Entity {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Relationship(type= "ENROLLED", direction= Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Enrollment enrollment = new Enrollment();

    public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
        return enrollment;
    }

    public void setEnrollment(Enrollment enrollment) {
        this.enrollment = enrollment;
    }

    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "ENROLLED")
public class Enrollment extends Entity {
    @StartNode
    private Student student;

    @EndNode
    private Course course;

    private Date enrolledDate;

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public Date getEnrolledDate() {
        return enrolledDate;
    }

    public Enrollment() {
    }

    public Enrollment(Student student, Course course, Date enrolledDate) {
        this.student = student;
        this.course = course;
        this.enrolledDate = enrolledDate;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to save this in Neo4j, it works fine. However in my scenario, the type of StartNode and EndNode objects are the same -

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyObject extends Entity {
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="CONNECTION")
    private MyConnection startConnection = new MyConnection();

    @Relationship(type="CONNECTION", direction= Relationship.INCOMING)
    private MyConnection endConnection = new MyConnection();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public MyConnection getStartConnection() {
        return startConnection;
    }

    public void setStartConnection(MyConnection myConnection) {
        this.startConnection = myConnection;
    }

    public MyConnection getEndConnection() {
        return endConnection;
    }

    public void setEndConnection(MyConnection endConnection) {
        this.endConnection = endConnection;
    }

    public MyObject() {
        super();
    }

    public MyObject(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@RelationshipEntity(type="CONNECTION")
public class MyConnection extends Entity {
    @StartNode
    private MyObject start;

    @EndNode
    private MyObject end;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public MyConnection() {
        super();
    }

    public MyConnection(MyObject start, MyObject end, String name) {
        super();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I try to save these using -

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = Neo4jSessionFactory.getInstance().getNeo4jSession();

        Student s = new Student("manoj");
        Course c = new Course("physics");
        Enrollment e = new Enrollment(s, c, new Date());
        s.setEnrollment(e);
        c.setEnrollment(e);

        MyObject startObj = new MyObject("Start Object");
        MyObject endObj = new MyObject("End Object");
        MyConnection conn = new MyConnection(startObj, endObj, "Connection");
        startObj.setStartConnection(conn);
        endObj.setEndConnection(conn);

        try(Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
            session.save(s);
            session.save(c);
            session.save(e);

            session.save(startObj);
            session.save(endObj);
            session.save(conn);

            tx.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

The student, course and enrollments objects get saved, but the two MyObject and the MyConnection objects don't get saved and I get the following exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData.classInfo(MetaData.java:76)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:389)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:319)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:262)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:528)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:420)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:319)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:262)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:370)
    at neo4j.ogm.ex.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Can you please help me to solve this -
1) Is it necessary that the StartNode and EndNode objects be of different types?
2) Is there some problem with my code or is it a shortcoming of the Neo4j OGM?

Thanks in advance,

Manoj.

Update after trying Luanne's suggestion -

Thanks Luanne. I tried your suggestion, though I had to specify the URL differently. I used - 
http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots
because by default it used https and I was getting some security exception and this dependency was not getting downloaded.

Anyways, with the 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT version, I still get the below error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.MetaData.classInfo(MetaData.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.haveRelationEndsChanged(EntityGraphMapper.java:391)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.getRelationshipBuilder(EntityGraphMapper.java:362)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:325)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:276)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelatedEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:571)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapRelationshipEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.link(EntityGraphMapper.java:329)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntityReferences(EntityGraphMapper.java:276)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.mapEntity(EntityGraphMapper.java:157)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.mapper.EntityGraphMapper.map(EntityGraphMapper.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:67)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.SaveDelegate.save(SaveDelegate.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.save(Neo4jSession.java:376)
    at neo4j.ogm.ex.Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

Comment: Which version of neo4j-ogm?

Comment: And have you provided the right set of domain packages to the SessionFactory

Comment: The version is 1.1.0, and yes, I am providing the correct package (in my case neo4j.ogm.ex.domain) which has all my domain classes.

Comment: Please try using 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT as issues related to this were fixed post 1.1.0. You'll need to include <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

Comment: Luanne, please formulate your comments as an answer :)

Comment: @mmwaikar please see the update to my answer. This wasn't a bug after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your intent to model `MyObject` to contain a single outgoing relationship type `CONNECTION` and a single incoming relationship type `CONNECTION` where each relationship has a property `name`?

[image: Sample subgraph]

So if we're looking at `EndObject`, then `startConnection` is the relationship with name `conn2` and `endConnection` is the relationship with name `conn1`?

If so, we might have a problem here. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-728

**Update:**
This wasn't a bug after all. The problem is the initialization you have in `MyObject`:

```
@Relationship(type="CONNECTION")
private MyConnection startConnection = new MyConnection();

@Relationship(type="CONNECTION", direction= Relationship.INCOMING)
private MyConnection endConnection = new MyConnection();
```

You've initialized both `startConnection` and `endConnection` to an invalid relationship entity i.e. one with no start and no end node.

In your test, you set the `startConnection` on `startObj` but not the end. In effect, the `endConnection` is represented by the invalid relationship entity.

Remove the initialization and it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luanne for your answer / suggestion. I came across your excellent article [The essence of Spring Data Neo4j 4](https://www.airpair.com/neo4j/posts/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4) and realized that my need is very similar to the Ingredient-Pairing example (mentioned in your article). For me, there can be a connection (MyConnection) between two objects (MyObject). So my modified code looks like this -

```
package neo4j.ogm.ex.domain;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;

@NodeEntity
public class MyObject extends Entity {
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type="CONNECTION", direction= Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private Set<MyConnection> connections = new HashSet<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<MyConnection> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void addConnection(MyConnection myConnection) {
        myConnection.getStart().getConnections().add(myConnection);
        myConnection.getEnd().getConnections().add(myConnection);
    }

    public MyObject() {
        super();
    }

    public MyObject(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}

package neo4j.ogm.ex.domain;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.EndNode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type="CONNECTION")
public class MyConnection extends Entity {
    @StartNode
    private MyObject start;

    @EndNode
    private MyObject end;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public MyObject getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public MyObject getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public MyConnection() {
        super();
    }

    public MyConnection(MyObject start, MyObject end, String name) {
        super();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And it works perfectly. I'll also try out your other suggestion of removing the invalid initialization.

Thanks again,

Manoj.